# Intuitive way to think about the derivative of an inverse function

Tags: calculus

I know that one can bring out the formula for the derivative of an inverse function using the chain rule, but is there an intuitive way to think about it? I can't seem to grasp it too well.

Comment: Geometrically, it is enough to think about what happens to the slope of a line (e.g. $y=mx+b$) when you reflect it over the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse of a function is $$f^{-1}[f(x)]=x,f[f^{-1}(x)]=x$$
Let's denote the inverse function of $f$ by $g$ then we have
$$g[f(x)]=x$$

Now take derivative on both sides of the above equation and we get,

$$g^{\prime}[f(x)]\cdot f^{\prime}(x)=1$$
Now lets say a variable $y=f(x)$
Replacing this we get
$$g^{\prime}(y)\cdot f^{\prime}(x)=1$$
So,
$$g^{\prime}(y)=\frac{1}{f^{\prime}(x)}$$